# Query Layer to access data on Sharepoint

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, sharepoint

I want to connect to a Sharepoint list from ArcMap.  Without knowing very much about these things I thought that it would be possible to read this non-spatial data to create lookup tables in my file geodatabase.  In searching for an answer, I can't seem to get away from ArcGIS for Sharepoint, which isn't what I'm looking for at all.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.0

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but I suggest looking at a Python library like [**python-sharepoint**](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint) to copy data from the Sharepoint list and then use ArcPy to write it into a file geodatabase table.

Comment: That one is tricky.  It has dependencies that need to be compiled from C and it's beyond my knowledge right now. Otherwise it looked like what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I need this functionality and asked Esri about it, with no success...

Another way to link ArcGIS and SharePoint is to show the ArcGIS attributes table in SharePoint as a list.
It is even possible to update it from SharePoint with SQL commands. This can be easily done with Tools like Layer2 bdlc or SharePointBoost Data connector. It is supported by Esri whith some restrictions (you can't use versioned database, shouldn't update ID columns or shape colums, etc.). I did it with an SQLServer Database but should work with Oracle.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I expect if it comes to 3rd party applications we'll end up using Access (which integrates well with sharepoint) to make a table from Sharepoint and then Arc can easily get at the table in Access...  Although I was hoping there was a more direct root that was easier to get at.  Oh well...